# Reachability Errors

Tags: ios6, reachability

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirstViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've looked over FirstViewController, reachability.h and reachability.m - It's clearly defined! And I've even added SystemConfiguration.Framework, as well as Reachability.m is in the compile list.

Any ideas? I'm losing my mind!
Pic attached.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef7MP.png

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If yes please share correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to remove references to Reachability.h and Reachability.m files from your xCode project. - Make sure it disappears from Compile Sources.
- Search you project's folder to make sure you don't have duplicates for Reachability.h and Reachability.m files in it
- Command+Shift+K to clean the project;
- Add Reachability.h and Reachability.m back to the xCode project;

Hope this will help.